# Dependence of numpy.random.shuffle()

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

I have a simple example.

```
import numpy as np

w=np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))
print w
#[[ 0  1  2] [ 3  4  5] [ 6  7  8] [ 9 10 11]]
q=w
np.random.shuffle(q)
print w
#[[ 6  7  8] [ 9 10 11] [ 0  1  2] [ 3  4  5]]
```

How do I create a new array q so that numpy.random.shuffle() doesn't effect w?

Comment: np.random.permutation ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

Comment: You just need to create a copy. There are multiple ways, `np.copy` is an easy one. As is `q` and `w` are the same object, ie `q is w == True`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you just need `q = w.copy()`